# Counting array values with corresponding values from a range at same index position in other array

Tags: c++

I have 2 C arrays in a c++ program as part of an interface between a c++ and c program, c++ vectors cannot be used.

And a number range of size end-start:

```
int start = 2;
int end = 4;
int range_size = end-start;
```

Here the range would include the values 2,3.

I need to count how often the values in the range appear in JA AND the value at the same index position in JB falls into the same number range (but can be any value in the range). I need the count in another array.

The expected result for the example above would be:

int result[range_size] = {2,2} i.e. 2 appears 2x in JA while the value in JB is a 2 or a 3, 3 appears also 2x while the value at the same index position in JB is 2 or 3.

```
int JA = {0,3,0,1,3,0,2,3,4,2,3,4};
            x     x   | |   | |
int JB = {0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4};
```

x = out of range in JB, | = in range in JB so the latter should be counted.

I tried the following but it's not working, the check whether it's in the range of JB seems to cause the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

int start = 2;
int end = 4;
int range_size;
int JA[12] = {0,3,0,1,3,0,2,3,4,2,3,4};
int JB[12] = {0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4};

range_size = end-start;
int result[range_size];


    int x = 0;
    for (x=start; x<end; ++x) {
        for (int a=0; a<12; ++a) {
            int y = JA[a];

            if (x=y) {
            int z = JB[a];

            if (z>=start && z<end) {
               result[x]++;
               printf("result[x] %i.\n", result[x]);
               }
            }
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Can someone spot the error?

In reality JA and JB contain thousands or even millions of int values and the range is also rather large, maybe there's another way to do it?

Finally this version worked:

```
int main()
{

int start = 2;
int end = 4;
int range_size;
int JA[12] = {0,3,0,1,3,0,2,3,4,2,3,4};
int JB[12] = {0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4};

range_size = end-start;
int result[2] = {0,0};

    int x = 0;
    int k;
    for (x=start; x<end; ++x) {
        for (int a=0; a<12; ++a) {
            int y = JA[a];

            if (x==y) {
            int z = JB[a];

            if (z>=start && z<end) {
               k = x-start;
               result[k]++;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    std::cout << "k = " << k << "\n";
               }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "result = " << result[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "result = " << result[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (x=y) ` - do you mean `if (x==y) `?

Comment: _"Can someone spot the error?"_ Sure, ***you*** can do using your debugger and stepping through your code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The programme can be simplified by writing a function that tests if a number is inside the range.
Another simplification is to have the outer loop corresponding to the index of the arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool in_range (int start, int end, int val){
    return (val >= start) && (val < end);
}

int main() {

    int start = 2;
    int end = 4;
    int range_size = end - start;
    int JA[12] = {0,3,0,1,3,0,2,3,4,2,3,4};
    int JB[12] = {0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4};

    std::vector<int> result (range_size, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        bool test = in_range (start, end, JA[i]) && in_range (start, end, JB[i]);
        if (test) result[JA[i]-start]++;
    }

    for (int val = start; val < end; ++val) {
        std::cout << val << " : " << result[val - start] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damien, this is a nice approach to match the entries in JA and JB but the result is not exactly what I am looking for. The result needs to be an array of size range containing the count of the numbers in the range. result[] = {2,2} as the numbers 2 and 3 match 2x a number in JB which is also in the range.

Comment: Programme modified